# NotifiyDataSetChanged does not work after using ListView setSelection() method Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

In one of my app , I am using notifyDataSetChanged to refresh List items , It works fine mostly but when I use ListView's SetSelction() method first (As i need to show any row selected when list load again) , that time list never get Refreshed by using notifyDataSetChanged.

I tried different tricks, but nothing helped .
Does any one know why notifyDataSetChange not working in this case and how can we solve this problem.

Comment: what happens if you made your `SetSelction` after **notifyDataSetChanged**? same result?

Comment: Generally It works with a jerk, but again after using SetSelction it does not work :(

Comment: considered a trick where you set the background of the item manually in the **getView(..)** by tracking the selected rows using array?

Comment: sorry I could not get your point

Comment: I have faced same problem, but I just remove selection procedure like you are doing. Instead doing that, take a touch event of list and then perform other logic to select list item.

Comment: but that will be a long and sledgy process as I have to auto scroll list to specific position when list reloads thats why I am using SetSelection, I also tried to use another trick used :: **runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
         mList.invalidate();
         
         mList.post(new Runnable() {
          
          
          public void run() {
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
         });
        }
       });**            :: But I don't think this is a perfect solutions as it does nt work many times :(